# What is the structure of diferric hexaphenolate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, transition-metals

I was studying about the ferric chloride identification of phenol, where one product formed is diferric hexaphenolate. But I am having trouble drawing out the structure of it. With ferric ion having a 3+ charge, it must be attached to three phenolate ions. But how can this ferric triphenolate be combined with the other Fe(III) ion and three more phenolate ions? And dative bonds from the other three phenolate ions to the ferric triphenolate doesn't seem to work.

I searched about it but I only found information about ferric triphenolate. I am now skeptical even about the existence of diferric hexaphenolate.

Comment: Related: [What is the product of the chemical reaction between phenol and ferric chloride?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43187/16683)

Comment: Are you looking for the structure of $\ce{Fe[Fe(OPh)6]}$? Look at these papers: http://science.sciencemag.org/content/118/3064/327    https://www.nature.com/articles/1651012b0    https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00966a011