# Structure of (CH3COO)3Fe

Tags: coordination-compounds, molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure

I'm a grade 12 student trying to comprehend MOT & LFT in Co-ordination compounds.
For one of our salt analysis(practicals), the test for acetate ion includes the addition of Neutral Ferric Chloride to salt solution.
This results in the formation of the above Co-ordination compound.
I've been obsessed, and I'm probably at the brink of insanity trying to comprehend it's structure via MOT/LFT. I have seen many Lewis structures but I'd really know to know it in terms of MOT. I assume it's octahedral in shape, with the 2 oxygen atoms of the carbonyl group acting as ligands; But I'm not sure, hence the assumption.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_acetate) ?

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01393501

Comment: @YUSUF HASAN yes I have, but it seems to be of no avail.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43187/what-is-the-product-of-the-chemical-reaction-between-phenol-and-ferric-chloride/43216?r=SearchResults#43216